# /usr/bin/java working only with sudo

Tags: java

I hope you can help me with the following problem.

I have a problem with installing oracle jdk. After installing using update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java
```

I can see all available alternatives are OK with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The problem is that the `java -version` is not working, but is working if I run it with `sudo`:

```
sudo java -version
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue? 
The same thing is also with `javac`

Comment: What's the output of "ls -l $(which java)" as a normal user? And what exactly is "not working", what error message do you get?

Comment: What are the permissions of the JDK folder?
Can you post the output of the command:



   $  namei -lo /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java

Comment: for namei -lo /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java the output is: f: /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root opt
drwx------ root root java
jdk1.7.0_71 - No such file or directory

Comment: By not working means I get: The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: for "ls -l $(which java)" is a long list, what I have to search for in it?

Comment: I fix the problem. The issue was on /opt/java folder who has the "700" permission. I change it to "755" and now the "java -version" is working with normal user without "sudo". I found that using "namei" command as Marcos Roriz Junior sugested. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you want you could help people with same problem writing this comment as answer and accepting it :)

Comment: Done. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem.
The issue was that the `/opt/java` directory had `700` permission. I changed it to `755` and now `java -version` is working for normal users (without `sudo`).